# MongoDB - How to remove the earliest item that meets the criteria

Tags: mongodb

Let's say that this is my collection:

```
[
    {
        "SKU" : "123",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    },
    {
        "SKU" : "123",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    },
]
```

I can remove 1 element like this:

`db.collection.deleteOne({SKU: '123'})`

But how can I specify that I want to delete the earliest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
    db.getCollection('test').find({SKU: '123'}).sort( { createdAt: 1 } ).limit(1).forEach(doc => 
        { 
            db.getCollection('test').remove({_id:doc._id})
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thought there would be a more elegant way. But this works. Thanks!

Comment: @devk Feel free to share If there is better or shorter query. I also seek for them but I can't find something better